# Modifying mongoose result modifies all document instead of one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have this function:

```
const getXNumberOfDocuments = async function getXNumberOfDocuments(
  page,
  results_per_page
) {
  /*************************************************** */
  results_per_page = parseInt(results_per_page);
  let x_number_of_documents = await Document.find()
    .populate([
      {
        path: "user",
        populate: {
          path: "profile",
          select: ["profileImageURL"],
        },
      },
    ])
    .limit(results_per_page)
    .skip(results_per_page * page)
    .lean();
  /*************************************************** */
  // I will stop this loop at i=0 by throwing an error
  // As you se below
  for (let i = 0; i < x_number_of_documents.length; i++) {
    console.log(" ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 295 ~ i", i);
    // #BUG:
    // For some reason this changes
    // profileImageURL for i=0 and i=1 as well
    x_number_of_documents[i].user.profile.profileImageURL =
      "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!";
    // await s3_config.getImageReadSignedUrl(
    //   x_number_of_documents[i].user.profile.profileImageURL
    // );

    /*************************************************** */
    // I check all documents here
    // And I find that profileImageURL was modified in all of them
    // Even though I stopped the loop at i=0
    for (let j = 0; j < x_number_of_documents.length; j++) {
      console.log(
        " j,",
        j
      );
      console.log(
        " ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 299 ~ x_number_of_documents[j].user.profile.profileImageURL",
        x_number_of_documents[j].user.profile.profileImageURL
      );
      console.log(
        " "
      );
    }
    /*************************************************** */
    throw new Error("STOPPING LOOP AT i=0");
    /*************************************************** */
  }
  return x_number_of_documents;
};
```

It usually returns something like this:

```
 const response = [
    {
      user: {
        profile: {
          profileImageURL: "https://xxxxxxx.com/xxx.jpeg",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      user: {
        profile: {
          profileImageURL: "https://xxxxxxx.com/yyy.jpeg",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      user: {
        profile: {
          profileImageURL: "https://xxxxxxx.com/zzz.jpeg",
        },
      },
    },
  ];
```

I am trying to modify `profileImageURL` in each object:

```
for (let i = 0; i < x_number_of_documents.length; i++) {
  console.log(" ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 295 ~ i", i);
  x_number_of_documents[i].user.profile.profileImageURL =
    "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!";
}
```

The problem is I find out that when `i==0`, instead of modifying `profileImageURL` **ONLY the first object**, it modifies it in **all objects**.

So when I break the loop after `i==0`, and log all the objects, I see that `profileImageURL` is the same in all of them:

```
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 291 ~ x_number_of_documents.length 5
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 295 ~ i 0

 j, 0
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 299 ~ x_number_of_documents[j].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
3asba
 
 j, 1
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 299 ~ x_number_of_documents[j].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
3asba
 
 j, 2
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 299 ~ x_number_of_documents[j].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
3asba
 
 j, 3
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 299 ~ x_number_of_documents[j].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
3asba
 
 j, 4
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 299 ~ x_number_of_documents[j].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
3asba
 
 ~ file: documents.js ~ line 204 ~ err Error: STOPPING LOOP AT i=0
```

Any idea what's going on?

---

To better explain this, I simplified the snippets above:

```
x_number_of_documents[0].user.profile.profileImageURL =
  "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!";
console.log(
  " ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[0].user.profile.profileImageURL",
  x_number_of_documents[0].user.profile.profileImageURL
);
console.log(
  " ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[1].user.profile.profileImageURL",
  x_number_of_documents[1].user.profile.profileImageURL
);
console.log(
  " ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[2].user.profile.profileImageURL",
  x_number_of_documents[2].user.profile.profileImageURL
);
console.log(
  " ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[3].user.profile.profileImageURL",
  x_number_of_documents[3].user.profile.profileImageURL
);
console.log(
  " ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[4].user.profile.profileImageURL",
  x_number_of_documents[4].user.profile.profileImageURL
);
```

So even if I explicitly, changed the first object, this is the result:

```
 ~ file: FILLING profileImageURL for i= 0
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[0].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[1].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_ofdocuments[2].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[3].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
 ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 308 ~ x_number_of_documents[4].user.profile.profileImageURL THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!
```

So the final result is like this even though I explicitly only modified the first object!

```
const response = [
  {
    user: {
      profile: {
        profileImageURL:
          "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    user: {
      profile: {
        profileImageURL:
          "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    user: {
      profile: {
        profileImageURL:
          "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!",
      },
    },
  },
];
```

---

Strangely enough, if I modify the `user` instead of `x_number_of_documents[0].user.profile.profileImageURL`, it modified only the first object:

```
const response = [
  {
    user: "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!",
  },
  {
    user: {
      profile: {
        profileImageURL: "https://xxxxxxx.com/yyy.jpeg",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    user: {
      profile: {
        profileImageURL: "https://xxxxxxx.com/zzz.jpeg",
      },
    },
  },
];
```

---

And if I modify `user.profile`, I get the same original problem:

```
const response = [
  {
    user: {
      profile:
        "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!",
    },
  },
  {
    user: {
      profile:
        "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!",
    },
  },
  {
    user: {
      profile:
        "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!",
    },
  },
];
```

So this may have something to do with modifying values in embedded documents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only first object of the array, you can break the loop by adding condition

```
for (let i = 0; i < x_number_of_documents.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) break;
  console.log(" ~ file: documentsServices.js ~ line 295 ~ i", i);
  x_number_of_documents[i].user.profile.profileImageURL =
    "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!";
}
```

and if the requirement is to update only first object of the array you don't need loop through the array, you can do as follows

```
if(x_number_of_documents.length > 0){
    x_number_of_documents[0].user.profile.profileImageURL = "New URL";
}
```

Comment: I want to update each `x_number_of_documents[i].user.profile.profileImageURL` with a different value. The problem is that even though I stop i=0, the objects where i>0 also get updated by the value that I put in the first object (i=0) which makes no sense.

Comment: Even simply doing this   `x_number_of_documents[0].user.profile.profileImageURL =
    "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM!";` modifies all the documents.

Comment: Check the code I added at the end of the question.

Comment: Can you share here the sample URLs data which you want to update?

Comment: You should have one more object which has URL data to be updated for the response, if you can share the URL object/array, i can provide you the solution accordingly

Comment: I already solved this. Check my answer.

Comment: Your question title is misleading and your expectations are different

Answer (score 0):

Still no idea what's causing this weird bug, but I managed to solved it like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < x_number_of_documents.length; i++) {
  x_number_of_documents[i].user = {
    ...x_number_of_documents[i].user,
    profile: {
      ...x_number_of_documents[i].user.profile,
      profileImageURL:
        "THIS SHOULD ONLY BE MODIFIED FOR i=0 BUT IT IS MODIFIED FOR ALL OF THEM! " +
        i,
    },
  };
}
```